# checking if all radio buttons are checked in jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable and i would like to check if all radio buttons are checked but this works only for the first paginated page but fails to check the other pages

this is my code:

```
var dt =  $('#newtable').DataTable({
          "paging": true,
          "lengthChange": false,
          "searching": false,
          "ordering": true,
          "info": true,
          "autoWidth": false
        });
```

This is what am using to check

```
 $("input:radio").change(function() {
   var all_answered = true;
   dt.rows().nodes().each(function() {
      if($(":radio:checked").length == 0)
      {
        all_answered = false;
      }

   })


  if(all_answered==true ){
      $('input[type=text]#general_comment').removeAttr("disabled");
      approvebtn.removeAttr("disabled");

  }else {
      approvebtn.prop("disabled", "disabled");
  }
});
```

Comment: You do know that's not what radio buttons are for, right?  Radio buttons are for "pick 1 of these otions" questions.  So they cannot be all checked

Answer (score 0):

You can `bind` a `page` event on your `DataTable` once the datatable is initialized, which on pagination (page change) will check what you want.

```
$('#newtable').bind('page', function () {
    //call to check what you want.
});
```